# Any way to syncronize AKMetronome with AKSequencer

Tags: ios, audiokit

I can't see any timebase variable for AKMetronome. It should be possible to synchronize AKMetronome with AKSequencer. how ?

Comment: upvoting. good question for beginners. upvoted against downvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metronome and the sequencer are different things.  If you want a metronome function in the sequencer, just make a click track.

Comment: Thanks Aurelius! Seems better to help than vote negative, can't understand that. Yes, I made the click track. I just wanted to use the callback function of AKMetronome.

Comment: headkit, as Aurelius said, I just made a click track and forget AKMetronome